# C++ Write in OOP... where to get started?

Tags: c++, function, class, oop, object

I'm really new to C++ and now I've confronted this issue that I really have no clue how and where to start from.

It's about rewrite an existing simple program using class and object. I read A LOT of books and online resources about OOP, I got the basic concept but I just really don't know how to use it in various different ways.

**I'm really sorry that my question was uncleared... Basically my question is, how could I rewrite this bit of code in Object Oriented Programming? (I hope this helps to clear up...)**
*-added at 5:29pm on 4/19/2014*

I've come to the dead end and struggling... Could someone please help me to get started? Even just give me a hint or suggest I'll be grateful!!

This is just a piece of the program that I wrote, I just want to know the steps to make it into OOP.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector < float > num;
    float sum = 0;
    float average = 0;
    int totalCount = 0; // total number count

    // Loop for read in total number count
    cout << "Please enter total number count\n";
    cin >> totalCount;

    sum = 0;
    // Loop for read in numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < totalCount; ++i)
    {
        num.push_back(0); // creates a space, must use this when vector is used
        cout << "\nPlease enter the number\n" << "Number " << i + 1 << ": ";
        cin >> num[i];

        sum += num[i]; // calculate the sum
    }

    // Calculate the average
    average = sum / totalCount;
    cout << "\n\nAverage: " << average << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _'I just want to know the steps to make it into OOP'_ Sorry! Either I don't get what you're asking for, or your question is way too broad ...

Comment: Sorry, I mean that I don't understand how can I rewrite the code that I've written into OOP style. I don't know where to start from.

Comment: May be you should first figure out how _OOP_ could improve the code you have?!?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the thing is... I really don't get how to start rewrite my code with OOP. I tried but then I found myself not using any setter/getter, constructor/destructor...etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand perfectly your question, but if you just need to write a class for it. You can do that in different ways..

1) if you want a class that is specific for float values, you could do something like this, is really simple but is just to show you an example..

```
class MyFloat{
    float _num;
public:
    MyFloat(float f = float()) : _num(f){}
    float getMyFloat() const{ return _num; }
    void setMyFloat(float b) { _num = b;}
};
```

2) if you want to have a class which will solve or handle whatever data type, then you will be looking in a template class that will look like this..

```
template <typename T>
class MyFloat{
    T _num;
public:
    MyFloat(T f = T()) : _num(f){}
    T getMyFloat() const{ return _num; }
    void setMyFloat(T b) { _num = b;}
};
```

Then in your implementation, you just create an object using your class, in this case MyFloat..

```
vector <MyFloat> num; // this will be an object that could handle float values or any type     depending which class you choose to use
```

I hope it helps, even tho your question was not too clear.. :)

Comment: Great way to show how pointless OOP can be. Write a wrapper around a float.

Comment: @DDrmmr _'Write a wrapper around a float'_ Or even better an `AverageCalculator` or alike ...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no concrete need to create an object. Actually you instantiate an object for the sequence of numbers (`num`).